# Unable to implement the function

Tags: python

Implement the function `isWhiteLine()`, which takes a string and returns TRUE if the
string contains only white space & tab characters. Program should read a file given as command-line argument, and print only non-blank lines onto the standard output.

```
import sys

def isWhiteLine(x):
    return x.isspace()

file_name = sys.argv[1]

f = open(file_name, "r")

for i in f:
    if (isWhiteLine(i) == False):
        print(str(i).strip())

f.close()
```

Comment: So what's the question about? You have some issues with your code or what?

Comment: Its throwing an error.  IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Menino Usually, Python raises up to 3 to 20 lines of errors (called the _traceback_). It'd help a lot if you could include the **full** traceback in your question. The IndexError you've shown us seems to be only _part_ of the traceback. But normally the traceback specifies the line number where the error occurred as well -- useful stuff.

Comment: Just eyeing your code though, it looks like it's coming from `file_name = sys.argv[1]`. Consider what happens if _no_ command-line arguments were passed into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should support what you are looking for.

```
import sys

def print_non_empty_lines(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                print(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print_non_empty_lines(sys.argv[1])
```